# Error with .bashrc file

Tags: bash, centos, centos6

I made some changes to the .bashrc file in the root folder of my CentOS 6 installation, then undid the changes and re-uploaded the file, but now I get a constant error message in the terminal window saying "line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file".

I'm at a loss and would be grateful if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong. The content is:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export LS_OPTIONS="--human --color=always"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -Al'
```

Comment: do you get the error on login or when you source it?

Comment: Did you do the editing on a non-Linux box and forget to convert the line endings?

Comment: I opened the file in MS Notepad and re-uploaded.

Comment: try `dos2unix .bashrc`. ALSO do you really mean "in the root folder "? Don't you mean $HOME folder? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the file was not saved in Unix format: I converted it and it now works.

Comment: Great - please mark this as the correct answer to indicate that this question does not need further attention.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is the problem, there are multiple files that are executed when you log in as a user, it might be something else.

try this:

```
cd ~
. .bashrc
```

and see if you get the error.   If you do, make sure the file is the same as you posted.

```
less .bashrc
```

Comment: I can't do that. There are three "command not found" messages after login, then .bashrc syntax error (line 18, sorry), then "-bash-4.1#".

Comment: that last item looks like the prompt (that you would be able to type those commands after). Are you not able to login?  If not, you would have ot login as another super user and edit the .bashrc or change the default terminal for the user.

Comment: Yes, it's the prompt. I can login via SSH, but I get "command not found" when I try the above, then the line 18 syntax error, and back to the prompt.

Comment: ok, do you get hte error on the changge directory command "cd ~" or on the "source .bashrc" command, or on the "less .bashrc" command?  Maybe use more instead of less?  "more .bashrc"